# Uncaught Error: no such table: test (code 1):

Tags: titanium, android-sqlite, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

### I'm using titanium and testing against an android emulator - but any advice relevant to iOs is also welcome! i am trying to use titanium with a database. I'm using the firefox sql lite plugin to make my db - so i make it, and then i go

```
var databasewindow=Ti.UI.createWindow({
    width:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor:"#bb7711",
    color:"#fff",
    font: { fontSize:48 },
    fontFamily:'BurnstownDam-Regular',
  layout: 'vertical'
});
var db=Titanium.Database.install('test.sqlite','test');
db.close();
var db = Ti.Database.open('test');

//db.execute('INSERT INTO test(name,age) VALUES('Humayoon','25')');
db.execute('INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES ("Humayoon")');
//db.execute('INSERT INTO test("name","age") VALUES ("'+'Zohaib'+'","'+'23'+'")');
var sql=db.execute('SELECT * FROM test');
while (sql.isValidRow())
{
  //var cityId = sql.fieldByName('id');
  var Name = sql.fieldByName('name');
  //var cityContinent = sql.fieldByName('age');
  Ti.API.info(Name);
  sql.next();
}
sql.close();
db.close();
databasewindow.open();
```

> error here

---

> [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [134,134] ----- Titanium
>   Javascript Runtime Error ----- [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main)
>   [0,134] - In app.js:15,4 [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main)
>   [1,135] - Message: Uncaught Error: no such table: test (code 1): ,
>   while compiling: INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES ("Humayoon") [ERROR] : 
>   TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,135] - Source: db.execute('INSERT INTO
>   test(name) VALUES ("Humayoon")'); [ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception
>   occurred at app.js:15: Uncaught Error: no such table: test (code 1):
>   , while compiling: INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES ("Humayoon") [ERROR] 
>   :  File: fail readDirectory() errno=2

---

Comment: "I'm using the firefox sql lite plugin to make my db", ok so you made it then how do you inserted that db in your titanium app?

Comment: before insertion its through uncaught error no such table test

Comment: before insert use `db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name)' );`